# Access relationship properties in shortest path search in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am fairly new to Neo4j and I'm trying to build a small example app: a public transport planner. It looks as follows (obviously strongly simplified example):

[image: simplified example]

The departure and arrival time of each bus (trip) is stored as a relationship property. I want the bus to leave near (or after) a specified time, while arriving as soon as possible after the departure (i.e. not necessarily the shortest, but the fastest route).

I have experimented a lot in Cypher, but I have not been able to do this. Any advice?

EDIT: updated diagram

[image: updated simplified example]

Answer (score 2):

To enable a simpler Cypher query, you can change your graph model to something like:

```
(:Trip)-[:LEG {start: 10, end: 20}]->(:Stop)-[:LEG {start: 30, end: 40}]->(:Stop) ...
                                        |                                    |
                                      [:AT]                                [:AT]
                                        |                                    |
                                        v                                    v
                                (Location {name: "Paris"})           (Location {name: "London"})
```

To summarize, each Trip consists of a chain of N Legs and N Stops. Each Stop is related to a Location, and each Leg stores its start and end times.

With the above model, the following query will return: (a) the path of the fastest Trip that started at or after time 40, and (b) the duration of that Trip.

```
MATCH p=(t:Trip)-[legs:LEG*1..]->(s:Stop)-[:AT]->(loc:Location)
WHERE HEAD(legs).start >= 40 AND NOT (s)-[:LEG]->()
WITH p, LAST(legs).end - HEAD(legs).start AS duration
RETURN p, duration ORDER BY duration LIMIT 1;
```

[Here is a console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=gdxpqa) that shows sample results.

Comment: I have been experimenting with your and my own solution and I got them both to work (the `LAST()' and `HEAD()' where crucial). However, I now have the problem (in both solutions) that, if I add more lines, it will sometimes start at stop a at time t, go to some stop and take the first bus there with time < t. I need to compare the relationship property before and after each stop, so that arrival time < departure time for each stop.

Comment: @Ben I think you are not using my model correctly. It is impossible to depart a Stop before you have arrived, because all the Stops in a chain are in strict chronological order. Perhaps you are reusing a Stop instance if you revisit the same location -- that is not allowed in my model (you have to create a new Stop, even if you revisit a Location). Does this address the issue? If not, please provide a set of data (say, in a console) that shows the problem.

Comment: I agree putting the stops in a chain is important. You have two models. The Trip (linked list of stops)  and the timetable (arrival and departure times which can also be modeled as deltas on the first stop and across timespans and certain weekdays (workday, weekend, holiday) and hour-ranges (rush-hour, morning, night, noon))